# build libcurl with c-ares

Tags: build, libcurl, c-ares

I want to build libcurl with c-ares,but come across a problem.

./configure --enable-ares and get output:

```
checking for perl... /home/liuwenyi/.jumbo/bin/perl
checking for gnroff... /usr/bin/gnroff
checking how to use *nroff to get plain text from man pages... -man
checking whether to enable c-ares... yes
configure: c-ares may not work properly with ipv6
checking that c-ares is good and recent enough... no
configure: error: c-ares library defective or too old
```

I try many versions and don't work.Is there someone figures this out?

Comment: You didn't tell us which versions you used. I suggest you use the latest version of libcurl and c-ares, as then you won't get these problems!

Answer (score 0):

For centos,you can use

yum install c-ares-devel openssl-devel

then make everything goes fun.